# SSH: Port 22 Connection refused

Tags: networking, 12.04, ssh, virtualbox, firewall

From Ubuntu 18 lts I'm trying to establish ssh connection with my Kali Linux VirtualBox on the same computer. I've already installed openssh-client and openssh-server on both systems and I'm connected to Internet via ethernet cable. 
So, I have 'enp2s0' interface (on both systems) which is found in 'ifconfig' and I changed my network ipv4 addresses to static with the same IP addresses I found in 'ifconfig':

In Ubuntu:

IP: 192.168.1.8

In Kali:

IP: 192.168.1.5

Netmask: 255.255.255.0 and Default Gateway: 192.168.1.255 are same on both systems.
In VBox settings for Kali I configured network to Bridge connection.
I checked ping between these systems and it is ok (64bytes..blahblah).
I turned off firewall on both systems:

sudo ufw disable

so it's inactive. The problem is that, I can connect from Kali shell to Ubuntu, but not vice versa where I'm getting the following message:

ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.5 port 22: Connection refused

I also tried with:  sudo ufw allow 22  on both and nothing.

sudo ufw ssh enable  didn't help.

Answers on comments:

`netstat -an | grep 22` gives me:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp       69      0 192.168.1.8:53436       13.32.28.22:443         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    3766327  /var/lib/samba/private/msg.sock/922
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    3805225  /run/wpa_supplicant/wlp3s0mon
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     2717922  /run/user/1000/bus
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     2869722  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     3802265  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     3802266  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     2335221  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     2341225  /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1822     /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     3773622  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     27122    /run/user/121/bus
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     3802298  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     3802297  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     2468922  
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    2339422  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     2332622  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     3853822  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     29227    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     29228    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     2329522  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     3766622  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     2329922  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     28122    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     2888122
```

Comment: do you have any firewall rules setup that would refuse an ssh connection? also `netstat -an | grep 22`

Comment: `192.168.1.255`, which is the last address of the subnet, is, by definition, the broadcast address and can't be the default gateway. Something is wrong in your configuration.

Comment: If that is true, how is it possible I can connect from Kali to Ubuntu, but not vice versa?

Comment: Try with `ssh -vvv <host-or-ip>` to get more verbose report. I'm not familiar with Kali but UFW is front-end for IPTables, so try to [remove all `iptables`rules](https://serverfault.com/a/200658/364207), maybe there still something.

Comment: The output of netstat posted above is on the Kali machine or Ubuntu? Make sure that openssh-server is installed and running and that port 22 is listening on the Kali machine. ```sudo apt install openssh-server``` You said you already installed it but just incase. ```sudo systemctl start sshd``` and then verify 22 is listening with that same netstat command.

Comment: Your netstat output is from the ubuntu machine. It would be more useful to see that output from the Kali machine... I am just going to assume that you just misread the default gateway information, your netmask indicates that 192.168.1.255 is not a usable IP there. I dont even think you could bring an interface up if you did that, but i don't think any of that matters, you already have comms. Some things to try on the kali machine.... `systemctl status ssh.service` `ssh 127.0.0.1` `systemctl enable ssh.service` ..... are you using ssh.socket?

Answer (score 0):

It can be that there is other server with same IP in your network... and that is why you get `connection refused`. Other case can be the way you have routing setted at your host. Please consult [this](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) documentation. So... you can have NAT for your virtual box, and "by accident" that is same address range as for host's NAT. Change connection settings to `bridged`, and retry.